# Combined p-value from wilcoxon test result on control experiment - interpreting the null-hypothesis correctly

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, experiment-design, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, combining-p-values

##### EDITED

I spotted error in my code, and now results are no more contradictory. But still I keep the question for utility of others and myself in understanding meta-analysis and correctly interpret null-hypothesis and results.

Please see below:

---

Also looking at:

- [Why is my combined p-value, obtained using the Fisher's method, so low?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158225/why-is-my-combined-p-value-obtained-using-the-fishers-method-so-low)
- [P-Values in Wilcoxon test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397023/p-values-in-wilcoxon-test)

###### Goal

I would like to test if samples of sequences are drawn from same population.
As controlled experiment, I am pooling sampling from the same population.
<strike>I am having contradictory results.</strike>

###### Data type

I am dealing with this data: I have sequences of animal sounds; the sequences expresses how frequent an utterance is in a repertoire (e.g. think like encoding a phrase with how often syllables are known to happen).

- The Population is sequences of an animal vocalizations, for observed contexts.
- The null hypothesis is: samples come from similar distribution.
- In the controlled experiment, the samples actually (or I believe so, based on the annotated dataset I am using) come from the same distribution, i.e. samples are pooled from the population of vocalizations belonging to the very same context.

When I apply Wilcoxon rank-sum on pairs of sequences pooled from the controlled experiment, I actually found majority of p-values > 0.05.

I run a simulation, and repeat the test 1000 times.
I apply Fisher's method on the group of 1000 p-values.

###### Interpret results of trials VS simulation: p-values of trials VS combined p-value from Fisher's method

I interpret the result of the majority trials as: **"there are very few trials where extreme results of significant difference are found, and the samples likely does not come from different distribution"**.

But then I apply Fisher, and found a `combined p-value` of almost 0.

Shall I interpret that the samples significantly come from different distributions ?

That is contradictory.

If correct, it is a result I failed to understand since the controlled group is from samples belonging to the very same  type of vocalisations.

I noticed that: the only situation when I have Fisher's p-value > 0.05, is when I test Wilcoxon on the whole population test against itself (I mean, the flattened array of all sequences of a vocalisation-type, against itself).

In this case, the p-value of Fisher is equal to the p-value of Wilcoxon, 1., for all the trials (i.e. it is a uniform distribution).

###### Dataset

The dataset consists in a series of sequences; the sequences' items represent how often a syllable is observed in a repertoire. Example:
`[170, 69]` is a sequence of two syllables, the first has been used 170 times, the second 69 times.

```
149                                             [170, 69]
254                                                  [37]
255                                                 [108]
256                                              [81, 46]
257     [20, 139, 69, 104, 43, 30, 46, 83, 71, 68, 92,...
                              ...                        
4671                             [116, 7, 31, 26, 97, 73]
4672                                             [71, 83]
4673                                                 [79]
5859          [68, 68, 65, 33, 68, 33, 65, 43, 87, 61, 1]
5931                                                 [66]
```

As controlled experiment, I would like to test if sequences are drawn from same distribution, as it should be because all sequences are known to be associated to a given context, based on empirical observations.

All those vocalization are from the same animal, and expressed for a given context.

I am using wilcoxon rank-sum test:

- sequences are said in independent events
- the distribution of syllables-frequences is not normal

###### Results

Sampling 2 random pairs sequences for 1000 trials, I got a Wilcoxon p-value list.

Only 18 trials out of 1000 has a p-value < 0.005

```
len(np.argwhere(np.array(corr_wilcoxon_matrix_list).flatten() < 0.05))
#18

# first 10 values:
# array([0.14891467, 0.43857803, 0.35453948, 0.31731051, 0.0808556 ,
       0.35453948, 0.31731051, 0.3358309 , 0.31731051, 0.24821308])
```

I compute Fisher's test against the p_value list:
result is `0.0810574489885437`

I noticed that, the higher the number of trials, the combined p_value tends to get lower and lower, and fluctuate more: it can be lower than 0.05 too.

Example:

- for 2 trials, with 1 random sample for each distribution: `rank_sum(sample_from_context, sample_from_context)`, I got combined p-value of : `1.0`
- for 10 trials, combined p-value: `0.98`
- for 100 trials, combined p-value: `0.02`
- for 1000 trials, combined p-value: `0.36`
- repeat 1000 trials, combined p-value : `0.08`

I thought possible answers could be that the size of sequences is different, and the longer the sequences, the more variability it has and the distribution of syllables may actually be different.

But I would like to have a point of view from people who are fond in statistics to interpret the meaning of this behaviour.

---

<strike>Basically Fisher's value will be always < 0.05, except when comparing the whole flattened array of historical data.</strike>

- Can you help understand: is the null-hypothesis in meta-evaluation (Fisher) the same of the null-hypothesis of the trials (Wilcoxon), or is it another thing ? I found difficult to understand what a distribution of p-values is, and what the null hypothesis of Fisher represents.
- Why cannot I use proportion of p-values in *independent trials* as an argument for statistical confidence ?
  E.g. "Since 982 trials had a p-value > 0.05, and only 18 had
  significance confidence that sequences were *not* from the same
  distribution, therefore there is 982/1000 probability of not meeting
  any extreme value, and therefore the simulation showed that the two
  samples come from the same distribution with  > 95% confidence."
- Why Fisher value is so low (0.08), if just 18 values are < 0.05 ?
- Why if I repeat the experiment for higher number of trials, the combined p_value fluctuate and get smaller ? Should not converge, for central limit theorem ? (I am tossing *n* independent simulations over and over)

<strike>- Should I conclude there is a flaw in the design of experiment ?</strike>

Comment: It would help if you could edit the question to provide more details about the data set, your simulations, and your tests. It might be something so simple as a very large data set giving "statistically significant" results of limited practical importance, or something else entirely. For example, if the null hypothesis holds, then not just a simple majority but approximately 95% of p-values should exceed 0.05 in multiple trials. Please add information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: Agree with @EdM. In particular, explain what this means, "But then I apply Fisher, and found a combined p-value of almost 0."

Comment: Thank you so much for willing to help! I found an error in my code. Now results are no more contradictory. Still, could you please help with an answer to understand meta-analysis ?